# Установка pygame для Python 3.4 в Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, virtualenv, pygame

Практически ничего не удается человечески установить ни через pip, ни прочими якобы удобными способами.

Стоит virtualenv в Ubuntu 14.04, создал в нем окружение на Python 3.4.

Сейчас уже часа 2 пытаюсь поставить pygame. Из кучи способов более-менее получается с описанным [здесь](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594781/how-to-install-pygame-and-livewires-in-ubuntu-14-04)

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial python3-pip libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
sudo pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

Для проверки создал питоновский файл со строчкой `from pygame import *`, когда запускаю его из виртуального окружения - ругается `ImportError: No module named 'pygame'. Если запустить не из окружения, то запускается без ошибок.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Ubuntu 14.04 нет официального `python3-pygame` пакета, поэтому следующий шаг -- использовать PPA, например, [`ppa:thopiekar/pygame`](https://launchpad.net/~thopiekar/+archive/ubuntu/pygame), рекомендованный на [AskUbuntu: How can I get pygame for Python3?](https://askubuntu.com/a/97721/3712)

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common && # для add-apt-repository
  sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:thopiekar/pygame && # где взять python3-pygame
  sudo apt-get update -y && # обновляем список пакетов
  sudo apt-get install -y python3-pygame # ставим
```

После этого `python3 -c 'import pygame'` команда должна работать.

Внимание: PPA могут содержать всё что захотят их авторы -- ставьте на свой страх и риск.

---

Если не из виртуального окружения работает, а в окружении не работает, то либо окружение создано для другой версии Питона или при создании virtualenv не включены системные пакеты (`--system-site-packages` опция) -- создайте окружение заново.

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло создание нового окружения. В процессе создания вспомнил что предыдущее окружение создавал без ключа --system-site-packages.
Теперь оставшиеся полдня буду пытаться поставить livewires

Comment: Поставил и livewires. Установил из скачанного пакета вручную, но опять же не с первого раза. Надо теперь проделать то же самое еще на 2 компах, может и найду закономерность глюков.